# matrix multiply with mpi

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, message-passing

I have a problem with the result of my m1 function when I check that some of the array between rank 0 and the last rank is empty and unfortunately none of the workarounds help to solve this problem.
Can anyone help me with this?
Where is the problem in this code?
And how can it be solved?
This is the code:
this is the code:

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define N 1000
#define M 1000 / 2

int A[N][N], B[N][N], C[N][N];
int m1[M][M], m2[M][M], m3[M][M], m4[M][M], m5[M][M], m6[M][M], m7[M][M];
int A11[M][M], A12[M][M], A21[M][M], A22[M][M], B11[M][M], B12[M][M], B21[M][M], B22[M][M];
int C11[M][M], C12[M][M], C21[M][M], C22[M][M];
int rank, size, start_row, end_row;

void multiplym1(int mySize, int AA[M][M], int BB[M][M], int CC[M][M], int DD[M][M], int resfinal[M][M], int mystart_row, int myend_row)
{
    int result1[mySize][mySize], result2[mySize][mySize];

    for (int i = mystart_row; i < myend_row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mySize; j++)
        {
            result1[i][j] = AA[i][j] + BB[i][j];
            result2[i][j] = CC[i][j] + DD[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = mystart_row; i < myend_row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mySize; j++)
        {
            resfinal[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < mySize; k++)
            {
                resfinal[i][j] += (result1[i][k] * result2[k][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("\n------------------------* Initializing matrices *----------------------\n");

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    start_row = rank * (N / size);
    if (rank + 1 == size)
    {
        end_row = N;
    }
    else
    {
        end_row = (rank + 1) * (N / size);
    }

    // printf("#%d: start is %d and end is %d\n", rank, start_row, end_row);

    for (int i = start_row; i < end_row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand() % 50;
            B[i][j] = rand() % 20;
            C[i][j] = 0;
            // printf("#%d: A[%d][%d] = %d\n", rank, i, j, A[i][j]);
        }
    }
    // printf("#%d: Done\n\n", rank);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // printf("#%d: start \n\n", rank);
    start_row = 0;
    end_row = 0;

    start_row = rank * (M / size);
    if (rank + 1 == size)
    {
        end_row = M;
    }
    else
    {
        end_row = (rank + 1) * (M / size);
    }
    // printf("#%d: start is %d and end is %d\n", rank, start_row, end_row);

    for (int i = start_row; i < end_row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {

            A11[i][j] = A[i][j];
            A12[i][j] = A[i][j + M];
            A21[i][j] = A[i + M][j];
            A22[i][j] = A[i + M][j + M];

            B11[i][j] = B[i][j];
            B12[i][j] = B[i][j + M];
            B21[i][j] = B[i + M][j];
            B22[i][j] = B[i + M][j + M];
        }
    }

    // printf("#%d: Done\n\n", rank);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // printf("#%d: start For M1\n\n", rank);
    start_row = 0;
    end_row = 0;

    start_row = rank * (M / size);
    if (rank + 1 == size)
    {
        end_row = M;
    }
    else
    {
        end_row = (rank + 1) * (M / size);
    }
    printf("#%d: start is %d and end is %d\n", rank, start_row, end_row);

    multiplym1(M, A11, A22, B11, B22, m1, start_row, end_row);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int *counts = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    int *displs = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        counts[i] = (M / size) * M;
        displs[i] = i * (M / size) * M;
    }
    counts[size - 1] = ((M / size) + (M % size)) * M;

    MPI_Gatherv(&m1[start_row][0], counts[rank], MPI_INT, m1, counts, displs, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("#%d: M1 DONE!!\n", rank);

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i += 49)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j += 100)
            {
                printf("#%d: m1[%d][%d] = %d\n", rank, i, j, m1[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}```
`
````

Comment: you need to use `MPI_IN_PLACE` in `MPI_Gatherv()`. I suggest you initialize your matrices with known values so you know what to expect

Comment: Also: lose the barriers. They don't do anything. And you probrably don't have stack overflow, but be carefully with allocating so much static memory.

Comment: how it possible that my array It is quantified just with my first and last processor
i mean when i use 4 processor, my array quantified with processor 0 and 3 and when i use 6 processor it work just on processoer 0 and 5